# `ngc` failed with angular material2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, angular-universal

I'm trying to build a Angular 4 Universal App, following this [guide](https://medium.com/@evertonrobertoauler/angular-4-universal-app-with-angular-cli-db8b53bba07d). However, it failed when I called `ngc` to generate `NgModuleNgFactory`, I got this error:

```
Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: /home/poi/Projects/solomon/src/app/module/archive/~@angular/material/theming
    at ModuleResolutionHostAdapter.readResource (/home/poi/Projects/solomon/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/compiler_host.js:370:19)
    at CompilerHost.loadResource (/home/poi/Projects/solomon/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/compiler_host.js:243:85)
    at Object.get (/home/poi/Projects/solomon/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24640:107)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (/home/poi/Projects/solomon/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13297:45)
    at /home/poi/Projects/solomon/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13426:53
    at Array.map (native)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._loadMissingExternalStylesheets (/home/poi/Projects/solomon/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13426:14)
    at /home/poi/Projects/solomon/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13429:26
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
Compilation failed
```

It looks like the compiler is trying to asscess a non-exist file `/home/poi/Projects/solomon/src/app/module/archive/~@angular/material/theming`, I imported `~@angular/material/theming` in my scss following [guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components).

So how to talk where the compiler the file is? :(

FYI, the version of `@angular/material` is `2.0.0-beta.5`, while `@angular/compiler` and `@angular/compiler-cli` are both `4.1.2`.

Comment: In which file exactly in your project do you have `@import '~@angular/material/theming';` as a statement? It should be in either `styles.scss` in the project root or within another file similarly referenced in your `.angular-cli.json` project file. If it's not in either of those places then it's in the wrong place.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry for the delayed response... I statemented it in `theme.scss` and I also mentioned it in my `.angular-cli.json`: `"styles": ["styles.scss","markdown.scss","theme.scss"]`.

Comment: @NeilLunn Hi. After a few try, I finally realized that I also had `@import '~@angular/material/theming';` in my `archive.component.scss` and I didn't reference it in my `.angular-cli.json`. Because I didn't want it to be global style. After removing `archive.component.scss`, `ngc` works just fine. Could you please leave an answer below so I can accept? Thanks!

Comment: The NGC compiler stack traces seem completely useless.  It traces itself, not your code.  Is this really expected behavior??